# How to populate a dropdown menu using JavaScript on multiple rows

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Am trying out an invoice generation system from, https://www.phpzag.com/build-invoice-system-with-php-mysql/. Demo on https://phpzag.com/demo/build-invoice-system-with-php-mysql-demo/create_invoice.php. Everything works just fine but the fields given as examples are just input fields. However, I need to use select options from my mysql database. The fields given in the “htmlRows” are supposed to be added as much as when the user wants using the add buttons in the html form. I have created a separate function for pulling the products from the database and now I don’t know why they are not being populated in the option values on the “htmlRows”.

```
             <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).on('click', '#checkAll', function() {           
                    $(".itemRow").prop("checked", this.checked);
                }); 
                $(document).on('click', '.itemRow', function() {    
                    if ($('.itemRow:checked').length == $('.itemRow').length) {
                        $('#checkAll').prop('checked', true);
                    } else {
                        $('#checkAll').prop('checked', false);
                    }
                });  
                var count = $(".itemRow").length;
                $(document).on('click', '#addRows', function() { 
                    count++;

                  //Load products
                  $.getJSON("load.php?task=products",{ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
                  var options = '<option value="">--------------------------- select -------------------------</option>';
                 count++;
                      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {


                                options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].display + '</option>';

                      }
                      $("select#productCode_'"+count+"'").html(options);
                  }); 

                    var htmlRows = '';
                    htmlRows += '<tr>';
                    htmlRows += '<td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>';

                    //This should be a drop down menu

                    htmlRows += '<td><select name="productCode[]" id="productCode_'+count+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" style="width:450px;font-weight:bold;"> <option value="">--------------------------- select -------------------------</option></select></td>';           
                    htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+count+'" class="form-control quantity" autocomplete="off"></td>';        
                    htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_'+count+'" class="form-control price" autocomplete="off"></td>';      
                    htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_'+count+'" class="form-control total" autocomplete="off"></td>';          
                    htmlRows += '</tr>';
                    $('#invoiceItem').append(htmlRows);
                }); 

            </script>
```

load.php

```
            case 'products':
            try
            {
                require_once("connect.php");

                $sql="CALL sp_getProducts()";
                $pdo = new PDOConfig();
                $resultset = $pdo->query($sql);
                foreach($resultset as $row)
                        {
                          $data[] = array(
                                  'id' => $row['ProductID'],
                                  'display' => $row['ProductDetails']
                                  );
                        }
                echo json_encode($data);


            }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                        die("Could not connect to the database\n");


            }

            break;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is `$(this).val()` in `{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}`?

Comment: Hi @AnkitSingh, It is not serving any purpose. We can even have {ajax: 'true'}. I have edited it. Since the SQL wont need any variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your javascript code with following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '#checkAll', function() {           
        $(".itemRow").prop("checked", this.checked);
    }); 

    $(document).on('click', '.itemRow', function() {    
        if ($('.itemRow:checked').length == $('.itemRow').length) {
            $('#checkAll').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('#checkAll').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });  

    var count = $(".itemRow").length;

    $(document).on('click', '#addRows', function(options) {
        count++;
        //Load products
        $.getJSON("load.php?task=products",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
            count++;
            var options = '<option value="">--------------------------- select -------------------------</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].display + '</option>';
            }
            console.log(options);
            var htmlRows = '';
            htmlRows += '<tr>';
            htmlRows += '<td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>';

            //This should be a drop down menu

            htmlRows += '<td><select name="productCode[]" id="productCode_'+count+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" style="width:450px;font-weight:bold;">'+options+'</select></td>';           
            htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+count+'" class="form-control quantity" autocomplete="off"></td>';        
            htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_'+count+'" class="form-control price" autocomplete="off"></td>';      
            htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_'+count+'" class="form-control total" autocomplete="off"></td>';          
            htmlRows += '</tr>';
            $('#invoiceItem').append(htmlRows);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```